# Connection to MySQL Server using RMySQL Library through Bastion in R

Tags: r, ssh, rmysql

On my local machine, I have ssh into the bastion where I can then connect to the remote MySQL server. I know that this is working because in terminal, it says that I have successfully connected and when I use an app like SQLPro and attempt to connect to the MySQL server with the correct permissions, I am able to successfully log in. Also, the command line

```
mysql -u username -p
```

works after I ssh.

Now, I am trying to use the library RMySQL to connect to the server and using

```
con<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "username", password = "pw", host = "127.0.0.1")
```

I get the return

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

It seems that R cannot determine that I have connected to the bastion. I say this because I have used the line above before on the remote server and it worked just fine.

Comment: To be more descriptive, here's the terminal command for ssh into the bastion

`ssh -L 13306:localhost:33750 ${USERNAME}@${BASTION_HOST} -t ssh -L 33750:localhost:3306 ${SERVER_IP}`

Answer (score 0):

```
con<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "username", password = "pw", host = "localhost")
```

If you have a workbench then go to server-> client connection and check the Host name. Your host name might be incorrect

Comment: This is not it, I'm connecting via a port so 127.0.0.1 should be appropriate. And again, I've tried to connect through the bastion using an app like SQLPro with the same credentials (i.e. "username", "pw", "127.0.0.1") and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running R on linux.

After a few hours of searching, the following documentation for AWS finally gave me the command I needed to connect to an RDS instance via an AWS bastion host:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/

The "syntax 2" at the above link worked for me to set up the tunnel:

ssh -i "Private_key.pem" -f -N -L 3306:RDS_Instance_Endpoint:3306 ec2-user@EC2-Instance_Endpoint -v

This successfully forwarded my local port 127.0.0.1:3306 to the RDS port 3306.

I then connected to the RDS instance from within R with just:

cn = dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user = "myDataBaseUserName", password = "myPassword", host = "127.0.0.1", dbname = "mySchemaName")